# Cannot download files

Tags: ubuntu-one, android

Using ubuntu one android with cyanogenmod-7. Whenever I click on a file to download the file the following error message pops up.

```
Error: can't create target directory.
```

Of course the file is never downloaded. The same occurs for folders.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer to my problem. The directory or file created had a space at the end of the filename. At least the android version of the app cannot handle a space at the end of the filename or directory name.

I figured out how the space was added. It was done automatically by my keyboard application.

I figured this all out by using "adb logcat" and examining the error message in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Android OS or Ubuntu One. However, this sounds like a permissions issue (maybe a bug?).

1. The error says it is trying to create a directory, but can't. What directory is it trying to create? What happens if you manually make that folder, and then try and download it?
2. Can you check the restrictions on the folder you are trying to download *to*? Is it set to read-only?